# Creating a mask with openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0

I'm a beginner with openCV,
I am trying to create a simple mask of 2 colors on the following image:
[image]

at the above image I want to mask the blue color - 0 and the black - 1.

everything else doesn't matter and be colored white.

I'm only able to mask the blue but not to 0.

Comment: Do you have any reproducible example code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](https://pythonprogramming.net/color-filter-python-opencv-tutorial/). That contains a video and an article about color masking. This essentially takes to  color values and masks anything in between them. You can use this strategy to create 2 masks I believe.